# FFMPEG concat cutting audio off after certain clip

Tags: python, ffmpeg

So I am creating multiple video clips in Python using FFMPEG, I am then trying to concat these together. I create multiple videos named result1000, result1001 etc, then I create a transition effect I want to layer between these videos. The result1000, result1001... etc concat together perfectly fine, however inserting the transition effect between them causes every clip after the first transition to lose audio.

**Creating the transiton**

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i media/templates/bg.png -i media/swoosh_sound.mp3 -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec libx264rgb output/swoosh.mp4
```

**Creating video clips**

```
ffmpeg -loop1 -y -i image_files/image+str(1000+i)+.png -i audio_files/audio+str(1000+i)+.mp3 -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec libx264rgb output/result+str(1000+i)+.mp4
```

The *ffmpeg_files.txt* then looks something like this

```
file 'output/result1000.mp4'
file 'output/result1001.mp4'
file 'output/result1002.mp4'
file 'output/result1003.mp4'
file 'output/result1004.mp4'
file 'output/swoosh.mp4'
file 'output/result1005.mp4'
file 'output/result1006.mp4'
```

and the concat command im using is

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i ffmpeg_files.txt output/no_bg_out.mp4
```

In console on running the concat comment it will say

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001f289b44c40] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
```

for each *resultXXXX* clip, then as soon as it reaches a transition clip it starts spamming

```
[mp4 @ 000001aa093ad100] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 13619623, current: 8777816; changing to 13619624. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

I have read over the solutions mentioned [Here](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/390400-ffmpeg-throwing-NNon-monotonous-DTS-in-output-stream) but none of them seem to solve my issue. It should be noted that all video clips are created from *.mp3* audio files and *.png* image files.

Comment: All inputs must have the same attributes. Need to see info about each input. Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i output/result1000.mp4 -i output/result1001.mp4 -i output/result1002.mp4 -i output/result1003.mp4 -i output/result1004.mp4 -i output/swoosh.mp4 -i output/result1005.mp4 -i output/result1006.mp4`

Comment: [Here you go](https://hastebin.com/iconeyosek.bash), put it in hastebin as its very long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All attributes must match, but `swoosh.mp4` varies from the rest with a different audio sample rate and channel layout. Re-encode the audio and try again:

```
ffmpeg -i swoosh.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -ar 24000 -ac 1 -b:a 32k swoosh2.mp4
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I have another clip that is also quite different and was wondering if you could help with the flags to re encode that to be correct. [Heres the output of a working video and the not working video](https://hastebin.com/wanekurida.bash)

Comment: @legit_hacker_2000 Add the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale). Luckily 2560x1440 scales down perfectly to 1920x1080 so it is simple: `ffmpeg -i beep.mp4 -c:v libx264rgb -vf scale=1920:-1 -c:a libmp3lame -ar 24000 -ac 1 -b:a 32k beep2.mp4`